# Extend Prawn::Document in Ruby Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am trying extend  Prawn::Document but it raise a undefined method `prawn_document' for #.

My class looks like this:

```
require "open-uri"
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/core'
require 'prawn/layout'

class M < Prawn::Document


  def initialize(options)
    options && options.merge!({:inline=>true})
    create_instance_variables(options.delete(:variables))
    super(options)
  end

  def render_template(template)
    pdf = self
    pdf.instance_eval do
      eval(template) #this evaluates the template with your variables
    end
    ensure_path
    pdf.render_file(File.join(output_path,filename))
  end

  private

  def create_instance_variables(vars)
    return if vars.blank?
    vars.each_pair do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end

  def output_path
    @output_path ||= File.join(Rails.root,'tmp','documents')
  end

  def ensure_path
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(output_path)
  end

  def filename
    @output_file ||= "#{Process.pid}::#{Thread.current.object_id}.pdf"
  end

end
```

Someone can help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You say it raised an error for # ?

Comment: The way I did was to write a helper `PdfHelper` and then define a class `PdfHelper::MyClass < Prawn::Document`. I am looking for a better solution. Have you found one?